# How do you get the next upcoming date from a table?

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on building a baseball website. On one side of the page I want to display information on the next upcoming game. I am using mysql ver. 5.0.45. My table is built as so:

opposingTeam, date, time, score

- Date is in the mysql date format (yyyy-mm-dd)
- I have found the datediff(date1,date2) command and tried experimenting with this with no luck

I have tried queries such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule
WHERE MIN(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date))
```

- But this gives me an arror because I am using the `MIN()` function wrong
- I am still pretty new to mysql and I just can not seem to figure this out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to display the next game (including today) you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to display all upcoming games use:

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `date`;
```

Comment: it is not displaying monthly and yearly wise, it means 2015 prints last row and 2016 prints first row even month also.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `date` > NOW() ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1
```

The `LIMIT 1` limits the query to returning one row, but if you need more than one, you can adjust the number accordingly (or omit `LIMIT 1` entirely, to fetch data for all future games)

Comment: it is not displaying monthly and yearly wise, it means 2015 prints last row and 2016 prints first row even month also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
select top 1 * from schedule where date>=CURDATE() order by date
```

Comment: I think 'top' is SQL Server only - not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to consider.

You are likely consigning yourself to eternal torment if you name a column "date".

The query optimizer is notoriously inept at optimizing queries that compare expressions and/or functions with values - try to use only column names.

Hence you should compare the value of the date column with, say, CURDATE(). (It's ok to compare a column value with an expression or function.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will change the name and keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT max(day) FROM schedule`

This gives the highest date from the table.

To get the next day, use :

```
SELECT  
DATE_ADD(max(day),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
FROM schedule
```

(I used "day" for your field "date")