# Is it possible to get the next date from an output?

Tags: mysql

I have a sql-query where I ask for some dates.

```
 "SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY date");
```

The output is:

```
2007-04-08
2008-04-12
2008-09-27
2009-12-06
2010-01-31
2011-02-27
2011-04-15
```

Now I'm wondering whether it is possible to get the next date from the output above.
Examples: 
1. Today is 2008-12-12. The next date would be 2009-12-06.
2. Today is today/current_date (2011-02-22). The next date would be 2011-02-27.

Have you got an idea how to specify the query?

Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering: You always want the next date or the closest date?
In the second case you might want to make the '>' a '>=' in the statement below, since the closest date might be actually the current date. see here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742928

Comment: Hi, I want the next date from the output. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table WHERE dateColumn > CURDATE()
Order by dateColumn desc
```

If you want only the NEXT date, then you can use LIMIT

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table WHERE dateColumn > CURDATE() 
Order by dateColumn desc
LIMIT 1
```